# Three20 Photo Viewer causes my layout to slide up

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, three20

thanks for any help with this.

I'm using the Three20 Photo Viewer in my app. Before I navigate to the photo viewer, all my views appear correctly, but after I click back out of the Photo Viewer, all of my content is slid up underneath my navigation bar.

Has any one experienced this, and found a solution?

Thanks for any help,

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TTPhotoViewController sets navigation bar to be translucent and also sets it's wantsFullScreenLayout to YES. You need to play with those in your controller (when you are back to it from photo controller) to fix stuff.

Comment: Yes, thanks. All I had to add was self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; in my viewWillAppear on the previous controller. Thanks Ariel.